# Wordpress Permalink not working

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

My wordpress website suddenly has broken.

It was running fine, but then suddenly the "Post name" permalink structure has broken. While other permalink structure are working, this one is broken.

I have disabled all plugin to test. But still the same problem. No new code has been incorporated in the website before it was broken.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks And Regards,
Rupak Banerjee.

Comment: What is the permalink string in your settings?
Did your .htaccess / rewrite rules change?

Comment: permalink string is "/%postname%/" . Nothing has changed and it has stopped working. It's infact opening the first post whenever any link is been clicked.

Answer (score 1):

In wordpress try clicking settings -> permalinks -> then save the settings as is, without updating anything.

This often rewrites the .htaccess file automatically and from past experience it has fixed sites I've worked with a number of times.